# How to use prime number theorem In such cases?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem

Let,
$$A(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}f(p)$$
Where $p$ is a prime number.
Under the Prime Number theorem we have that,
$$\pi(x)=Li(x)+O\left(\frac{x}{e^{a\sqrt{\ln(x)}}}\right) $$
as $x$ approach infinity.
Now,
$$A(x)=\sum_{k\leq x}f(k)(\pi(x)-\pi(x-1))=\int_{2}^{x}f(u)d\pi(u)$$
Now how to use the Prime Number theorem to simplify that Integral further?

Comment: If $f$ is reasonable (e.g. differentiable), then you can integrate by parts and try to use the prime number theorem to study the other side. Depending on $f$, this may or may not be sufficient to get a good understanding of $A(x)$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you mean $A(x)=\sum\limits_{k\leq x}f(k)(\pi(k)-\pi(k-1))$?

Comment: From the definition of logarithmic integral, it is natural to believe $\sum_{p\le x}f(p)\approx\int_2^x{f(t)\over\log t}\mathrm dt$ when $f(x)$ is continuously differentiable and satisfies certain other good properties.